# 2 monitor (extended) on 1 PC running windows 7

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

My PC's graphics card has 2 slots: 1 HDMI and 1 VGA

I have 2 monitors: 1 with DVI-D and VGA, and another with VGA only

I would like to run 2 monitors with extended display. What is the best solution/cable I would need? I think I will need to get a new monitor with dvi, or can I get away with buying just a cable? System is Windows 7.

Comment: You don't need a new monitor. A cable/adapter should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

You could go VGA -> VGA for the first display and then get an HDMI -> DVI-D adapter for the second display. A quick Google search will show many results for the converter cable.